# SPSS combine count and compute

Tags: spss

Is something like this possible in spss?
COMPUTE new_var = (COUNT var1 to var5 (1))*2 + (COUNT var1 to var5 (2))*3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by myself:

```
COMPUTE myindex= 0.
DO REPEAT v=var1 TO var5.
   DO IF v=1.
      COMPUTE myindex= myindex+2.
   END IF.
   DO IF v=2.
      COMPUTE myindex= myindex+3.
   END IF.
END REPEAT.
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested syntax.

```
RECODE var1 to var5 (1 = 2) (2 = 3) (else = 0) into tmp1 to tmp5.
COMPUTE new_var = sum(tmp1 to tmp5).
```